# How do I use test cases for competitive programming? CodeChef C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I've just started getting into competitive programming on CodeChef and I was working on this challenge and for the most part, it works, but I'm not sure how to implement the test cases. I've seen solutions where people use a while loop and decrement the T, I tried that but I had no luck.

Here is the Problem statement:

Problem: If Give an integer N . Write a program to obtain the sum of the first and last digits of this number.

Input: The first line contains an integer T, the total number of test cases. Then follow T lines, each line contains an integer N.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// First and Last Digit

int main() {
// your code goes here
// 1. T for test cases
int T;

// 2. Get input from N;
int N;
cout<<"Enter number: ";
cin>>N;

// 3. Convert int to string
string convert = to_string(N);

// 4. Get index [0] and [string length - 1] 
string first;
string last;
for(int i = 0; i < convert.length(); i++)
{
    first = convert[0];
    last = convert[convert.length() - 1];
}

// 5. convert single digit to int
int firstDigit = stoi(first);
int lastDigit = stoi(last);

// 6. add both numbers
int total = firstDigit + lastDigit;

// 7. output both numbers
cout<<total;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The same way you use test cases for noncompetitive programming.

Comment: Modern, if you can call 2011 modern at this point, C++ allows you to replace `convert[0]` with `convert.front()`. That's not very cool, but the counterpart of `convert.back()` is much easier on the brain than `convert[convert.length() - 1]`. Both have the same failure case of empty strings, but such is life. Make sure you got a string and you're ready to roll.

Comment: That loop doesn’t do anything useful; it just extracts the first and last characters over and over again. Also, don’t store those two digits in strings; store them in two `char` variables. And, finally, to convert a character that represents a digit to the value that the digit represents, just subtract `’0’`.

Comment: Come on @PeteBecker, let's not waste time on silly conversions to string, or `char` juggling. We have an `int N;`. `N <mystery op> 10` gives me `N`'s last digit. Add a second *mystery op* and a loop, gives me the first digit. A third *mystery op* gives me the sum. No `std::string` anywhere. This is a math formula problem, testing knowledge of elementary math and logic, nothing more.

Comment: If you read the number as a string, `std::getline(cin, string_as_number)` you won't need to read the input as a number then convert.

Comment: There are more things in heaven and Earth, @SamVarshavchik, than are dreamt of in your philosophy.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik — you’ve been misled by the problem statement. The input is **text**, and the problem is simply extracting the first and last characters, converting them to values, and adding them. The math is trivial.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  I tend to disagree.  The workload of a programmer is to take  challenges, like numerical problems, and convert them into code.  That's exactly what competitive coding demands.  It sure doesn't help for analysis of large systems, but no one will ask that from a junior programmer.

Comment: If you are a skilled, experienced developer, @MichaëlRoy, then feel free to waste time solving as many meaningless coding puzzles as you want. But this what you will see when you visit these scam sites: "Just solve these coding puzzles, and you'll become an instant C++ uberhacker!!! If you have any questions, just go to Stackoverflow". Hence the non-stop flow of this kind of garbage, here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  Didn't you notice I said **junior** programmer?  I also said that I do agree with you that coding puzzles won't be of much help to more senior programmers.  I've also seen books that  claim "Just read this book and you'll become a star coder in a few days!", and that sure ain't true either.  What makes a solid programmer is coding and reading good code.  Not reading a book. As to garbage questions, we all know they mostly come from college students who will never enjoy coding, and are only enrolled in  computer "for career and money".  They'll never be good programmers.

Comment: Coding puzzles have no tangible value to anyone, senior or junior, @MichaëlRoy. There's nothing wrong with useless coding puzzles being used as a mildly entertaining time-waster, if something has nothing better to do. There's nothing wrong with that. Unfortunately, too many entry-level and junior programmers get misled into buying into a popular myth about a secret shortcut to becoming an elite C++ guru: throw away your C++ textbook, and do these coding puzzles. And the end result is this constant stream of garbage.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  A task _is_ a puzzle, with the only difference being that that you're (hopefully) paid to solve it..  That's how I see it, and that's what keeps programming fun for me.  I am quite certain I'm not the only one to see it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Competitive programming is fun!  It's a good exercise for writing compact and fast code.

Don't be thrown off by the term 'test cases', it's just a fancy name for 'numbers'.  First read T, then read N, looping T times.

Something a bit like that:

```
size_t T;
std::cin >> T;

while (T--)  // loop T times
{
    std::string N;  // read N as a string
    std::cin >> N;  // this will skip all whitespace and only 
                    // give us the good stuff. \n is a whitespace.

    // ...

    auto sum = (N.front() - '0') + (N.back() - '0');

    // ...
}
```

Comment: General rule of thumb: If you're not using a number like you normally would a number, you're probably better off with a string.